# Protractor image comparison: is it possible to ignore one specific element and compare the rest of layer with elements

Tags: image, module, protractor, comparison

I'm using protractor-image-comparison for Protractor, which is highly useful in comparing screenshots of the page. Currently I have a situation where I have a top header layer in which a time element is displayed. As other elements on this layer are not grouped together, I would still like to compare the whole top header layer, but just without time element.

Is that even possible?

In the following picture time element is marked with red, which I want to avoid comparing, but still would like to compare the rest of the elements, but not separately as I would like to know if any of the elements changed their position.

[image: top header - time element marked in red]

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, it is possible... should read the manual thoroughly. If you have the same troubles, here you can find an example:

https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-image-comparison/blob/master/docs/index.md

Go to checkElement example.

Comment: How did you compare whole screen by skipping just one element, The link you shared is not working.

Comment: I guess I found it. Thanks!!   https://github.com/wswebcreation/protractor-image-comparison/blob/master/docs/OPTIONS.md